# Transpaprent QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, transparency

```
#include <QtGui>

class   Label : public QLabel
{
public:
    Label(QWidget *parent =0) :
        QLabel(parent)
    {
        resize(100, 100);
        setText("hello");
        show();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Label l;

    return a.exec();
}
```

This outputs a label 'hello' with a background. I'm using Qt4. I want to make the background of this label completely transparent. But *setWindowOpacity* changes the whole widget transparency. I want the content as it is, but only the background to be transparent.

Comment: There's an article titled "Transparent Backgrounds in Qt 4.1" here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq16-background.html Will this work for you?

Comment: @aldo - the Nokia document no longer exists online.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found this as simpler....

```
QWidget::setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use stylesheets to set the color and the alpha value of the background:

```
setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0%)");
```

Answer (score 5):

In PyQt:

> lbl.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

Answer (score 3):

If you define a `QColor` with alpha of `0` you will get background with transparent color, so for example:

```
QColor bg_color(255, 0, 0, 0);
QPalette p(l.palette());
p.setColor(QPalette::BackgroundColor, bg_color);
l.setPalette(p);
```

Which should make label's background whatever color transparent.

Answer (score 3):

In my case with Qt5, the following worked:

```
movieLabel->setAutoFillBackground(false);
```

Tested both with Qt 5.11.1 and Qt 5.8.0.